# What information does log_civicrm_group keep? How is it useful?

Tags: database, groups, mysql, logs

Do you use the log_civicrm_group logs? Our log file is now about 300MB - quite crazy. Are records of removal and adding contacts to groups stored here? Thats information we would like to keep. How do you use log_civicrm_group?

Latest Wordpress / Civi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There had been an issue recently where way more 'changes' where logged than intended: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/449.

Can you verify that it is still growing way too fast since running on a patched version?

The information you are looking for is stored in the table `civicrm_subscription_history` aswell as `civicrm_group_contact` for current status.

With `log_civicrm_group` you could track how the title, description or hierarchy of a group change over time.

Comment: I emptied the table - looks like it was just logs from prior to the fix. I will monitor the situation and report back if its out of control again. Thanks for the answer!