Entries in Log Tables
Some of our log tables are rather large and we're curious as to how the logging process works. We'll have static groups that have and 'Update' log entry during times when no one has actively updated the group with more or fewer contacts. While we have lots of groups and are actively deleting groups that are no longer needed, is there a way to only log times when a group actually changes rather than seemingly random times when nothing seems to change?

Is it possible that you are on an outdated version of civiCRM? Your question reminds me of this issue:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/34475/15405

While we may not have the most recent version of Civi, my thoughts are that the version isn't the issue. We're using 5.74.5. Also, we've had this issue for quite some time (even after various upgrades) but are just now getting around to addressing it.

Right, this may be another issue then. What kind of entries do you have in log_civicrm_groups?

It appears that most of the log entry types are 'Update' and they belong to groups that have a saved search ID.
